# Pictures in DOC file

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

I have file in format DOC (MS Word 97-2003) and I want to get list of all images used in this file. I try to use "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" namespace like in code below

```
Application application = new Application();
Document document = application.Documents.Open(dataPath);

var words = document.InlineShapes;
int count = words.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (words[i] != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", i, words[i].PictureFormat);
    }
}
```

but I can not find any image in this file (in real there exists two images). Maybe I do something wrong? Could you recommend me any library, which will easy it. I can'nt convert file to DOCX

Comment: While editing I change "var words = document.Shapes;"
to "var words = document.InlineShapes;"

Comment: Count is equal 2, but when "I am in if" I get COMException: Element doesn't exists in collection ...

Comment: please edit your question instead of adding (strange) comments? Also, consider to change the name of the words variable to something more like 'inlineShapes'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.InlineShapes` to grab the images.

Comment: InteliSense doesn't give "ActiveDocument" as available property.

Comment: @Jacek, does it give you the `InlineShapes` property right off of the `document`?

Comment: I can write: document.InlineShapes

Comment: Count is equal 2, but when "I am in if" I get COMException: Element doesn't exists in collection ... (please look code above)

Comment: @Jacek, is that the inner exception? The inner exception holds the __actual__ COM exception.

Comment: @Jacek let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17398/discussion-between-mike-and-jacek)

Answer (score 0):

It may be funny, but in this case, I think, the numbering goes from 1. That's why you get COMException: "Element doesn't exists in collection".

Try:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    if (words[i] != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", i, words[i].PictureFormat);
    }
}
```